# how to save data if gridview has dropdownlist in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

gridview has dropdowblist for approval, how to select specific record and save the data.

Gridview

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  CellPadding="3" Font-Size="Smaller" Height="210px" Width="670px" BackColor="#DEBA84" BorderColor="#DEBA84" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellSpacing="2" style="text-align: left">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="class_id" HeaderText="Class_id" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="module_id" HeaderText="Module_id" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="lecturer_id" HeaderText="Lecturer" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="student_id" HeaderText="Student_id" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="submissionDate" HeaderText="Recieved" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="end_date" HeaderText="Submission_Date" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ec_details" HeaderText="EC" />
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Approval">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblApproval" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("acceptance") %>' Visible = "false" />
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddAcceptance" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddAcceptance_SelectedIndexChanged">
                <asp:ListItem>Approval</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#F7DFB5" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#A55129" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <PagerStyle ForeColor="#8C4510" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <RowStyle BackColor="#FFF7E7" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#738A9C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFF1D4" />
                    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#B95C30" />
                    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1E5CE" />
                    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#93451F" />
                </asp:GridView>
```

code behind

```
 protected void btTOapprove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand com = conn.CreateCommand();
    conn.Open();
    com.Parameters.Clear();
    com.CommandText = "UPDATE [Marking] SET [acceptance]=@acc where [class_id]=@cid AND [module_id]=@mid AND [student_id]=@sid";
    com.Parameters.Add("@acc", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = 
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();


}
```

when user select approval for example Yes or No, user must click save button to save data. How to select specific record and save its approval process.

Comment: You need approval code?

Comment: approval code already shown in code behind above

Comment: you can put a check box column so when clicking approve button you will just loop on each row and if the checkbox is checked then it's approved.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply make approval void for that :

```
void approval()
    {
        if (yes)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection"].ConnectionString);
            SqlCommand com = conn.CreateCommand();
            conn.Open();
            com.Parameters.Clear();
            com.CommandText = "UPDATE [Marking] SET [acceptance]=@acc where [class_id]=@cid AND [module_id]=@mid AND [student_id]=@sid";
            com.Parameters.Add("@acc", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value =
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            //Cancel the process
        }
```

Then you can use the void :

```
protected void btTOapprove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        approval();
    }
```

Update :

You can also make void for getting the value and send them to string.

```
void getvalue()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < comboBox1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            string str = comboBox1.Items[i].ToString(); ;
        }
    }
```

Comment: com.Parameters.Add("@acc", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = (how to get dorpdownlist value here)

Comment: @Algiri You can add what you want.

Comment: I must get the value from ddApproval, but when i want to use it, it shows an error!